# What CSS (or JS?) animation has this button?

Tags: javascript, css, button

I actually came across this theme on ThemeForest:
http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/58888.html

And I was wondering on how to achieve the animation effect the two buttons in the slider have (the 'buy intense now' and 'start a journey' buttons). I've checked the code behind it with Firebug, but had a little rough time understanding everything, so I tried to Google the animation and came across Hover.css. That wasn't exactly what I was looking for, so I was wondering if anybody can explain the way of achieving this effect?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which buttons, name them...

Comment: Just inspect the code, everything is there.

Comment: Show us what you have tried ? Also post your attempts(failed) to understand the problem..

Comment: @ParagBhayani He is probably talking about "Buy intense now" and "Start a journey" buttons. They animation techinque is pretty interesting indeed.

Comment: Never thought that  someone will use :before and ;after elements THAT way.

Comment: @IdeaMan : yah still trying to understand, how it is doing that ... pretty interesting...

Comment: You first must understand how pseudo elements work.And how to animate them(with CSS, don't do this with Jquery).
Basically you place the white dots outside of the button, then on hover animate the 2 white dots with translateX, once they are in the middle of the button, you use transform:scale()

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusing question and am also sorry for not posting my attempts. I actually just used another animation and because therefore I've used hover.css, I thought maybe for this one was also a specific css file already available. I couldn't find it, that's why I've asked this question here. Thanks for the great tips, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the code below. You can adapt it to get the effect you want.

HTML:

```
<section id="button-container" class="section">
  <div id="effect" class="button">
    <span class="text">Button</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.section {
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
}

.button {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 25px 50px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
}
.button .text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  font-size: 2em;
}

#button-container {
  background-color: #fff;
}
#button-container #effect {
  background-color: #42b574;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#button-container #effect .text {
  color: #fff;
  transition: all .5s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s linear;
}
#button-container #effect::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  transition: top .5s ease-in .5s, width .5s ease-out, height .5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: top .5s ease-in .5s, width .5s ease-out, height .5s ease-out;
  left: 50%;
  top: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #79ccf2;
}
#button-container #effect:hover .text {
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: color .5s linear .5s;
  -webkit-transition: color .5s linear .5s;
}
#button-container #effect:hover::after {
  transition: top .5s ease-in, width .5s ease-out .5s, height .5s ease-out .5s;
  -webkit-transition: top .5s ease-in, width .5s ease-out .5s, height .5s ease-out .5s;
  top: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

You can find the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6mjrth8m/)

Answer (score 1):

It has everything done in CSS, you need to inspect its HTML and CSS to get more idea about which CSS properties the person has used.

I have noticed few things and will share it with you

1. Element Structure
    It has Anchor tag and inside that there is span, anchor tag has two pseudo elements, before and after so you can say that it look like this
   `[o======o]` so here 'o' shows pseudo elements(:before and :after) and '=====' is span element
2. he has set certain CSS for this elements like background color on anchor element, hide before and after pseudo elements, put before pseudo elements 20pixels more left and after to 20 pixels more right, and hide those pseudo elements by setting it as transparent
3. Now he has written some more CSS on hover of all these 3 elements, like showing them in the view with transformations, animations, webkit-transform css.
4. and on hover he has animated before and after pseudo elements from left and right to center using various CSS properties.... he has changed background-color of the element as well.

So if you do this all together step by step and able to get every CSS transformation and Animation right you will be able to do this animation aswell

I was able to pluck out some CSS properties and tried to made it dummy but I couldn't succeed more than this... but you can give it a try more and get what you want, here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EJxFg/1729/)